# Why do pasta leftovers lose flavor and creaminess in the following days?

Tags: pasta, italian-cuisine

I don't expect pasta to be el dente out of the fridge. However with red sauces it seems like there is way too little sauce and too much fat at the bottom and not on the noodle.

When I combine the fresh pasta and sauce the sauce seems to perfectly coat each noodle. The pasta is creamy and flavorful. But the day afterwards the creaminess is gone and so is the even dispersion of flavor and sauce on the noodles.

Leftover white sauces are worse. Again, they are creamy and flavorful when I combine them with the noodles, but as time passes the sauce breaks and loses flavor.

The only pasta that I make that doesn't suffer this atrophy is spagetti alla puttanesca and lasagna.

Why does that happen, and can I prevent this?

Comment: Are you refrigerating them mixed (in which case, the fact the noodles soften gives you a clue what happens - they suck all the water from the sauce!)?

Comment: If you have fat at the bottom you are putting too much fat in the sauce.

Answer (score 1):

Foods tend to get worse in the fridge regardless of what you do. You lose the freshness in exchange for preserving them, and that's that. Here's some general tips for keeping food afloat in your fridge, in case you aren't already doing them:

- Store your food in tupperware containers, ziploc bags, or other airtight storage
- Put an open box of baking soda in your fridge
- Adjust the temperature settings of the fridge

Beyond that, how are you re-heating them? Re-heating things through the stove or oven will always turn out better than the microwave, and I'm not sure if I need to explain why.

And, some more pasta-specific advice here - store the noodles and sauce separately. The noodles will absorb all the moisture otherwise, hurting the flavor of the overall dish and resulting in clumps of fat, uneven sauce dispersion, or worse.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick for the white-sauce pastas. After you take out the reminders from fridge, add little milk and microwave it. This works fine for Alfredo.